# why is $\Gamma(1)\setminus H$ a 2-sphere with one point missing?

Tags: general-topology, elliptic-curves, modular-group

I am reading Silverman's book about elliptic curves.

$\Gamma(1):=SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})/\{\pm 1\}$ is the modular group, and $H$ is the upper half plane. The author says that the geometric description of $\Gamma(1)\setminus H$ is the fundamental domain, and then he gives the picture.

[image]

I understand the fundamental domain part, but I don't understand why it is(topologically) a 2-sphere with one point missing.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of gluing in topology? If you glue together the boundary as indicated in the diagram, you will get a 'cylinder' whose bottom is closed but the top is open and extends out infinitely. Now you can expand the hole in the $2$-sphere and stretch the sphere out in the same way. Infinite stretches are ok as long as you do them continuously, e.g., the stereographic projection.

Comment: @ParthivBasu Oh thank you. Your explanation is perfect. I understand it now.

Comment: @EricSun Then you should give an answer to your question.